# External links are not 'Loading'? (by clicking with the left mouse button)

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, heroku, slim-lang, middleman

Good night,

I'm riding a landingpage for a retreat that will happen in my church, I'm working out with (middleman / frameworks [bootstrap] / HTML slim [ruby] / heroku), I'm creating a standard link, but when I click with the left button it does not load link more when I right button and open in new tab, loads normally?

obs .: "Internal link is functioning normally"

I thank you for your attention.

page link -> https://retiroespiritual.herokuapp.com

Follows the code:

```
  /! contatos
  #contato.scroll
  .box2
    .container
      center
        .row
          br
          h2 Contato
          br
          br
          br
          br
          .col-md-3
            i.fa.fa-envelope.fa-4x
            br
              h4 ibiconexaototal@gmail.com
          .col-md-3
            i.fa.fa-phone.fa-4x
            br
              h4 41 9658-7321
          .col-md-3
            i.fa.fa-whatsapp.fa-4x
            br
              h4 41 9658-7321
          .col-md-3
            a href="https://www.facebook.com/conexaototalibi"
              i.fa.fa-facebook-square.fa-4x
              br
                h4 conexaototalibi
        br
        br
        i.fa.fa-arrow-circle-o-up
        a.scroll href="#home" <b>  voltar ao topo</b>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your page is rendering such that `div.col-md-3` is *inside* your `<a>` tag, and it's that div that is positioned. Since it has `float:left`, the `<a>` tag renders as 0px x 0px so it's not clickable.

It's not clear to me what's wrong with the slim syntax that's causing the `<div>` to be nested inside the `<a>` though.

Comment: Good even if I place a measure for <a> it does not become clickable with the left mouse button over only with the right , will be problem in JavaScript ? @embden

Comment: No, it's not JavaScript; it must be a problem with the HTML. Your link above is no longer working though so I can't check out the page.